# How does getrusage() report time spent hibernating?

Tags: c, profiling, posix, getrusage

I am currently using `getrusage` to tell me how much time I spend in my application's event loop.

I wonder how this will be affected by hibernating. Is hibernation time reported at all? Or perhaps as system time? Is this specified somewhere in Posix or is this system dependent?

**Edit** Asking the same question for Windows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246869/how-does-getthreadtimes-report-time-spent-hibernating).

Comment: AFAIK POSIX does not know about hibernation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think POSIX mentions hibernation anywhere, so it is technically platform dependent.

I can only speak for Linux, but other UNIX variants - and perhaps even Windows - probably behave similarly, since this is what makes most sense.

In Linux, the exact details of what happens under the hood with hibernation are described in Documentation/power/swsusp.txt under the kernel source. In short, user processes are sent a fake signal that causes them to switch to `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` state. A process in the `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` state is taken out of the run queue and put to sleep until the condition it is waiting for comes true, so time spent in `TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE` is neither counted as user time nor as system time. If you were to measure runtimes with `time(1)`, you would at most see that it contributes to wall clock time.

With `getrusage(2)`, you won't see a difference in any of the reported CPU times because the process wasn't runnable.

So, to answer your question: hibernation time is not reported at all.